# Close TCP session every on schedule, optional monitor idle state

Tags: linux, tcp, firewall

Good day.

I need an application or script on Linux firewall which will monitor and close idle TCP connections to one site after some minutes. Till now I found cutter and Killcx, but this is command prompt tools and no idle detection.

Do you know any app or maybe firewall implementation for Linux with everything that I want in one package?

Thanks.

Comment: This belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can hack something with "**conntrack**" iptables module. Especially the --ctexpire match. See man iptables.